# Create dictionary of Comparable and Hashable keys?

Tags: swift, generics, dictionary

This seems to be very basic question, but haven't been able to find an answer to it.

Here is what I've tried

```
var items = [Comparable: [NSObject]]()

var items = [Comparable, Hashable: [NSObject]]()

var items = [protocol<Comparable, Hashable>: [NSObject]]()

typealeas Key = T where T: Hashable, T: Comparable
var items = [Key: [NSObject]]()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `Comparable` nor `Hashable` can be used as types by themselves, because they contain `Self` in their definition, and can only be used as generic constraints.

It wouldn't really make sense anyway, if you think about it, for your dictionary to be able to have keys of different comparable types, because each comparable type can only compare to its own type, not others.

If you have a dictionary that's only going to have a certain particular comparable, hashable type, you can make the function or class that contains this code generic and constrain the type parameter there:

```
func foo<T : protocol<Comparable, Hashable> >() {

  var items = [T: [NSObject]]()

}
```

Comment: I get your point, but I can't do just Hashable either. [Hashable: [AnyObject]]. I can't use generics on the class itself because the dictionary is being instantiated inside a UIViewController, and generics don't work with Objective C classes

Comment: @aryaxt: Like I said, you cannot use `Comparable` or `Hashable` itself as a type. I don't understand why your view controller would need to have a dictionary of an unknown comparable and hashable key type.

Answer (score 2):

An update to @newacct's answer:

As of Swift 4.2, the `protocol < >` syntax is no longer used. Instead use `&` like so:

```
<T: Comparable & Hashable>
```